# How to separate 'Subtotal' and 'amount' to match theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm stylizing our storefront, and I'm looking to separate two divs to match the theme. When all product options are selected and add-ons are selected, I'd like the amount to be justified to the right, and the 'Subtotal' to be justified to the left. Is there any way of separating the two in CSS?

I've tried justify-content: space-between to no avail

[image: Screen Shot of desired result]

[link to website](https://www.fralinpickups.com/product/modern-paf/) *Note, you'll have to fill in product options & choose an add on for the content to appear above the Add to Cart button.

Comment: please can we see the pertinent code

Comment: `div.product-addon-totals .wc-pao-subtotal-line {
float: left;
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 10px 0;
margin-top: 20px;
}`

Comment: `justify-content: space-between` won't work because the "Subtotal" is a text element and the price "332" is a children inside the parent. Did you try using 
`.wc-pao-subtotal-line .amount {
    margin-left: 6em;
}` https://prnt.sc/okh292 You may need to change the spacing for different screen size.